# Is it possible to create an app for a site without an API?

Tags: mobile-phones, mybb

I would like to create an app for a myBB forum. So the site on the forum will look nicer and much more cleaner on an iPhone or Android.

Is it possible without an API? It isn't my site ether.

Comment: Check this out: http://phpdave.com/MyBBIntegrator/

Answer (score 1):

everything is possible, it's just a matter of resources...

technically, you can write an app for everything on the web, but:

- an API will tell you how you can do things with the site, without having to reverse engineer all pages/posts/..., and the format of every output resulting from post/get operations. reverse engineering may take a long time, and you will surely not come accross all possible results (error pages, bad authentication...);
- an API is quite stable and is always updated with great care from the developpers so as not to break existing applications. without an API, there is no guarantees that your app will not break with the next release of the forum when it is upgraded;
- a web API generally defines an output format which is easily parseable: many API outputs XML or JSON, which can be processed with standard libraries. without an API, the output format is plain HTML, which may be difficult to reorganize in order to show the results in a different format.

so, yes, you can definitely write an app for a myBB forum, but it may require a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do, it's called screen scraping and is what was done before XML, the semantic web, SOAP, web services and then JSON apis tried to solve the problem better.

In screen scraping, you grab the site's HTML, parse it, get the data you want out of it, then do what you need with that data. It's more work, and breaks each time the site's layout changes, hence the history of improvements to it.

You mention the site in question is not yours. Many sites do not regard screen scraping as fair use, so check with the site's terms and conditions that you can legally create an app from the data posted there.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider useing HTML5 ... do you think it doable for use app ?